# Difference between Type Class and Algebraic data types

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, fantasyland

As I understand the **Type Class** is that it's not something concrete but just a construct for ad-hoc and parametric polymorphism. **Eq** and **Semigroup** are examples of type classes. On the other hand, there is **Algebraic data type**, which is a concrete composite type, for example, **Either** and **Maybe**. And they are also **Functors**.

So, there is a specification for Algebraic data types for JavaScript: https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land.
On this page, **Setoid**(Eq), **Ord** and **Semigroup** are also ADT. But is it correct? If so, they are composite of what types?

I also find out this article regarding type classes, and here Functors and Monads are type classes. https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html#type-classes-in-cats.
And, is it means that **Either** and **Maybe** are type classes as well?

Is **Eq** a *type class* or *algebraic data type*? Or both? Same for Functor

Comment: The fantasyland is about algebraic structures, not algebraic data types. And that table on the Scala cats page lists *instances* of implicits.

Comment: To answer the question at the end, `Eq` and `Functor` are both type classes, not types. (In the context of Haskell, "type" and "algebraic data type" mean the same thing.) But I don't think I can write a "good" answer because I don't know what is making you confuse these two fundamentally different things.

Comment: As a first approximation, in Haskell you can think of type classes as _sets_ of types, e.g. `Num = { Int, Integer, Float, Double, ... }` is the set of numeric types and `Eq = { Int, Bool, (), [Int], Maybe [(Int, Double)], ... }` is the set of types whose values can be compared with `==`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond technically in GHC today with the `ConstraintKinds` extension, constraints are types and (single-parameter) type classes are types of type `Type -> Constraint`. Also, not all types in Haskell are algebraic data types (even in Haskell2010 there is the type of functions `A -> B` which is not an algebraic data type).

Comment: thanks @Noughtmare, it's easy to fall into the trap of oversimplification!

Comment: @RobinZigmond *"To answer the question at the end, `Eq` and `Functor` are both type classes, not types."* Since the question is tagged with `Scala` too, I'll add that in Scala, according to the spec, `Eq` and `Functor` are types too. Type constructors belong to so called *non-value types* https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#type-constructors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081904/scala-difference-between-a-typeclass-and-an-adt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534671/type-classes-vs-algebraic-data-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We collect data (values, terms) into *types* (data types). We can collect types into *type classes*.

`1`, `"a"`, `true`, `Some(1)`, `None`, ... are values. They belong to types, `Int`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Option[Int]`, ... Types can belong to type classes, `Eq`, `Ord`, `Functor`, ...

ADT (algebraic data type) is a data type constructed via sum and product

```scala
// Scala
sealed trait MyTrait
case class MyClass1(i: Int, s: String) extends MyTrait
case class MyClass2(b: Boolean) extends MyTrait
```

```hs
-- Haskell
data MyTrait = MyClass1 { i :: Int, s :: String } | MyClass2 { b :: Bool }
```

Here `MyTrait` is a sum of `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`. `MyClass1` is a product of `Int` and `String`. `MyClass2` is a product of single multiplier `Boolean`.

There are also data types that are not ADT. E.g. function types `A => B`, <strike>union types `A | B`</strike>, intersection types `A & B` or `A with B`, existential types, etc. Scala ADT are automatically generalized ADT ([GADT](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT)) in Haskell terminology. There are generalizations of ADT in dependently typed languages, [Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%CE%A3_type)- and [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%CE%A0_type)-types (i.e. dependent sum and product).

Type classes is FP way to describe a behavior (via ad hoc polymorphism, early binding, static/compile-time dispatch). We can make a type an *instance* of a type class

```scala
// type class
trait MyTypeclass[A] {
  def foo(a: A): Unit
}
object MyTypeclass {
  // instances
  implicit val myTraitMyTypeclass: MyTypeclass[MyTrait] = new MyTypeclass[MyTrait] {
    override def foo(a: MyTrait): Unit = a match {
      case MyClass1(i, s) => println(s"MyTrait: MyClass1: i=$i, s=$s")
      case MyClass2(b)    => println(s"MyTrait: MyClass2: b=$b")
    }
  }
  implicit val myClass1MyTypeclass: MyTypeclass[MyClass1] = new MyTypeclass[MyClass1] {
    override def foo(a: MyClass1): Unit = println(s"MyClass1: i=${a.i}, s=${a.s}")
  }
  implicit val myClass2MyTypeclass: MyTypeclass[MyClass2] = new MyTypeclass[MyClass2] {
    override def foo(a: MyClass2): Unit = println(s"MyClass2: b=${a.b}")
  }
}
```

```hs
class MyTypeclass a where
  foo :: a -> IO ()
  
instance MyTypeclass MyTrait where
  foo (MyClass1 i s) = print ("MyClass1: i=" ++ show i ++ ", s=" ++ show s)
  foo (MyClass2 b)   = print ("MyClass2: b=" ++ show b)
```

Here `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, `MyTrait` (in Haskell only `MyTrait`) are types, they are instances of the type class `MyTypeclass`.

An alternative to typeclasses (another way to describe a behavior) is OOP inheritance (via subtyping polymorphism, late binding, dynamic/runtime dispatch)

```scala
sealed trait MyTrait {
  def foo(): Unit
}
case class MyClass1(i: Int, s: String) extends MyTrait {
  override def foo(): Unit = println(s"MyClass1: i=$i, s=$s")
}
case class MyClass2(b: Boolean) extends MyTrait {
  override def foo(): Unit = println(s"MyClass2: b=$b")
}
```

We can *lift* an ADT into a type class. For example standard ADT

```scala
sealed trait Option[+A]
case class Some[+A](a: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

```hs
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

can become a type class and its instances

```scala
trait Option[A]

case class Some[A](a: A)
case object None
type None = None.type

implicit def someOption[A]: Option[Some[A]] = new Option[Some[A]] {}
implicit val noneOption: Option[None] = new Option[None] {}
```

```hs
class Maybe a
 
newtype Just a = Just a
data Nothing a = Nothing
 
instance Maybe (Just a)
instance Maybe (Nothing a)
```

> On this page, `Setoid`(`Eq`), `Ord` and `Semigroup` are also ADT. But is it correct? If so, they are composite of what types?

Normally, `Eq`, `Ord`, `Semigroup` are not ADT. They are not constructed via sum and product. They are type classes. They describe behavior, namely how to compare elements for equality, how to compare them for order, how to add elements, what is unit element. They "consists" of all types declared as their instances, e.g. `Int`, `String` etc. (i.e. where the corresponding behavior is implemented in some specific way).

> is it means that `Either` and `Maybe` are type classes as well?

Normally, `Either` and `Maybe` are not type classes, they are ADT. But if we really want we can lift ADT into a type class as I showed above.

> Is `Eq` a type class or algebraic data type? Or both? Same for `Functor`.

`Eq` and `Functor` are type classes, not ADT.

Answer (score 10):

The underlying root of your confusion is distinguishing concepts from implementations.
So let's try to make some of those clearer.

## Typeclasses

Is a pattern to achieve polymorphism; punctually, ad-hoc polymorphism.

In some languages those are a feature provided by the language; e.g. **Haskell** or **Rust**.
Others, allow you to express them using other features; e.g. **Scala** using implicits, meaning that they are values in this language while they aren't in **Rust** *(AFAIK)*
And finally, in theory, you may model them in any language, but you would need to pass the instances manually, this is what is usually called the strategy pattern; an example is **Java**'s `Comparator`. Some folks argue that if the value has to be passed explicitly then is not a typeclass, I personally disagree but let's not open that pandora's box.

## Algebraic Data Types (ADTs)

Is a pattern to model data based on simple constructors known as products and unions.

Again, some languages provide the building blocks for those out of the box, like **Haskell**. Some others emulate them upon classic subtyping and objects with some help from the compiler, like **Scala**.
And, once again, you may in theory model them in any language and replace pattern matching with a `fold`. But, in this case, I do agree that if the UX is not pleasant and you don't have pattern matching built-in in the language is hard to talk about ADTs.

## Functor

Is an abstraction, a concept derived from category theory.
In essence, it is constituted of three things:

- A type `F[_]` of kind `* -> *` *(commonly know as type constructors)*; e.g. `List`
- An implementation of `map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]` for the given type `F`
- A formal proof that such implementation satisfies the `Functor` laws.

I won't attempt to explain what a `Functor` is here...
But, a quick TL;DR; is that it represents the possibility of transforming some context by applying a function to the value(s) it will compute.

Since a `Functor` is an abstraction, we need some form of polymorphism to represent it.
Experience has shown us that typeclasses are the most natural way to model `Functor`, `Monad`, `Monoid`, etc. But, you may try to use other approaches like structural types or subtyping... but really, you will hit a wall sooner than latter.

## Extras

On top of all that, we also need to add other layers of indirection that each language may have.
For example, in **Scala** we use subtyping to model typeclasses hierarchies, so `Monad[F] extends Functor[F]`, and the same keyword to model both subtyping abstractions and typeclass abstractions `trait`.

So again, it is important to always separate concepts / ideas from their underlying implementations; at the end of the day, everything will be just electrical pulses on a weird machine :p

Answer (score 3):

Algebraic Data Types and typeclasses are both "things with multiple types", and I *think* that's what's confusing you. I think the reason we're having a hard time answering your question (or even figuring out precisely what it is) is because other than that they have almost nothing in common.

A typeclass could be thought of as a *contract* or *specification*. It exists independently of any concrete type and they are *open*: and any type you come up with could implement the necessary details to be a member of the set. We specify this in different ways in different languages that include this concept.

For instance Rust traits like `Display`:

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct Foo(i32);

impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}
```

Or Haskell typeclases like `Show`:

```hs
data Foo = Int deriving Show
```

We have created in both cases a very basic type `Foo` based on the integer type that implements the "has a string representation" typeclass in the respective languages. As I said before the set of types that implement `Show/Display` is *open*: we can do this forever with any applicable type we come up with.

Contrast that with `Maybe`, which is a tagged union (which qualifies it as an Algebraic Data Types) `Just a | Nothing` for some type `a`. The set of types in the `Maybe` union is *closed*: you can use any type `a` you want but you can't add new things to the union.

`Maybe` is a *type* (or to be more precise, a type constructor), not a *typeclass*. It's meaningless to say that `Foo` implements/derives `Maybe`. `Maybe` is not a set of rules for some other type to follow, *anything* could be a `Maybe Whatever`.

But `Maybe` as a type does *implement* some typeclasses, for instance the `Monad` typeclass (and by implication `Functor`, `Applicative`, etc.). It is *not* meaningless to say that `Maybe` implements the `Monad` specification.

Comment: *"Maybe is a type, not a typeclass."* Well, "Maybe" (as well as other ADT) can be "made" a typeclass https://ideone.com/wE58V4

Comment: @DmytroMitin that's a neat trick, is it actually possible to capture the semantics of Maybe that way though?

Comment: I guess so. Ordinary functions working with `Maybe` become class members and are implemented in instances. We just lift data constructors into types and ADT into a class.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I doubt you could implement [`listToMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe) with that, since you don't know which concrete type it returns. `>>=` would be even harder. Also what stops me from declaring `SomethingElse` to be an `instance Maybe`?

Comment: @Bergi bind is what I was thinking of when I asked if it would be possible to implement the semantics of Maybe that way

Comment: @JaredSmith "*`Maybe` is a type*" - some people might disagree and say that `Maybe` is a type *constructor* while `Maybe a` (or `Maybe Int`) is a type.

Comment: @Bergi *"I doubt you could implement `listToMaybe`..."* I guess I can. Implementation #1 https://ideone.com/gDwobi #2 https://ideone.com/v3HwhH *"Also what stops me from declaring..."* Nothing stops. ADT are closed, type classes are open, type families can be closed or open.

Comment: @JaredSmith See the above comment

Comment: @Bergi *"some people might disagree and say that `Maybe` is a type constructor"* Depends on a language. I already wrote in comments that for example in Scala according to the spec type constructors are types.

Comment: @DmytroMitin "*I guess I can implement `listToMaybe`*" - well now you've used a type-level `List`. Can you do it with a normal list, something like `listToMaybe :: Maybe b a => [a] -> b a`? How would you construct a `Maybe` dynamically, say from user input?

Comment: @Bergi Type classes is compile-time technique (this will not work with dynamic input or `Maybe b a => [a] -> b a` -- at compile time we don't know whether the list is empty). I see, you meant the ordinary list. My original point was that OP's confusion of ADT vs. type classes is understandable since from some point of view ADT can be "made" a type class. Surely, lifting ADT into a type class is not a universal replacement.