# Ad-hoc Polymorphism vs. Data Constructors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, adt, typeclass

Defining different data constructors for a type, and then defining functions using pattern matching over them resembles ad-hoc polymorphism in other languages a lot:

```hs
data Shape = Circle Float | Rectangle Float Float
area :: Shape -> Float
area (Circle r) = pi * r^2
area (Rectangle a b) = a*b
```

Using type classes you could do

```hs
class Shape s where
    area :: s -> Float

data Circle = Circle Float
instance Shape Circle where
    area (Circle r) = pi * r^2

data Rectangle = Rectangle Float Float
instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle a b) = a*b
```

One advantage of the second that I see is that it can be extended without touching existing declarations, in particular it may be your only option. Are there other reasons to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Maybe relevant: [the expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). The first is closed on the constructors (you can't add new cases later on) but is open on the operations it allows (you can easily define a new function on shapes later on). The second one is instead open on the cases, but closed on the operations.

Comment: The obvious advantage of the first is that you will find yourself writing better Haskell programs if you learn to prefer it to the second.  I am only partly joking.

Answer (score 3):

To make the 2nd approach work, you have to know the type `s` at compile time while with the 1st approach you can match runtime values

```
data Shape = Circle Float | Rectangle Float Float

area :: Shape -> Float
area (Circle r) = pi * r^2
area (Rectangle a b) = a*b

fromString :: String -> [Float] -> Shape
fromString "circle" (r:_) = Circle r
fromString "rectangle" (a:b:_) = Rectangle a b

areaFromString :: String -> [Float] -> Float
areaFromString s params = area $ fromString s params
```

[Difference between Type Class and Algebraic data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74961117/difference-between-type-class-and-algebraic-data-types)

[Scala: difference between a typeclass and an ADT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081904/scala-difference-between-a-typeclass-and-an-adt)

[Type classes vs algebraic data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534671/type-classes-vs-algebraic-data-types)

Answer (score 2):

To compare these approaches, it helps to see more than the data type declarations.

Suppose we want to write a Haskell program to parse a shape specification and display it as an ASCII diagram on the screen.

#### Solution #1

One method is to define our `Shape` as an ADT:

```
type Pos = (Float, Float)
type Scalar = Float

data Shape
  = Circle Pos Scalar
  | Rectangle Pos Scalar Scalar
  deriving (Show)
```

To parse the specification, we'll use Megaparsec.  This will require a `Parser Shape`:

```
shape :: Parser Shape
shape = Circle <$ char 'C' <*> pos <*> scalar
    <|> Rectangle <$ char 'R' <*> pos <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar
```

plus some additional `pos` and `scalar` parsers (see below).

To render the shape, we'll first calculate its bounding box:

```
data Box = Box Pos Pos deriving (Show)

bbox :: Shape -> Box
bbox (Circle (x,y) r) = Box (x-r,y-r) (x+r,y+r)
bbox (Rectangle (x,y) w h) = Box (x-w/2,y-h/2) (x+w/2,y+h/2)
```

and then write it to a raster over that bounding box:

```
type Raster = [[Char]]

render :: Box -> (Int, Int) -> Shape -> Raster
render (Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) (cx,cy) s
  = [[ if inShape (x,y) s then 'X' else ' '
     | x <- [x1',x1'+delta..x2']] | y <- [y1',y1'-delta*caspect..y2']]
  where --- ugly computations of x1', etc. go here
```

This relies on a function that can determine if a raster point is inside the shape or not:

```
inShape :: Pos -> Shape -> Bool
inShape (x,y) (Circle (cx,cy) r) = sq (x-cx) + sq (y-cy) <= sq r
  where sq a = a*a
inShape (x,y) (Rectangle (cx,cy) w h)
  =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
    && cy-h/2 <= y && y <= cy+h/2
```

After adding some driver/main functions and filling in the details, the full program is:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec hiding (Pos)
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

type Pos = (Float, Float)
type Scalar = Float

data Shape
  = Circle Pos Scalar
  | Rectangle Pos Scalar Scalar
  deriving (Show)

type Parser = Parsec Void String

shape :: Parser Shape
shape = Circle <$ char 'C' <*> pos <*> scalar
    <|> Rectangle <$ char 'R' <*> pos <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar

pos :: Parser Pos
pos = (,) <$ char '(' <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar <* char ')'

scalar :: Parser Scalar
scalar = do
  sgn <- option 1 (-1 <$ char '-')
  dig1 <- digits
  dig2 <- option "" ((:) <$> char '.' <*> digits)
  return $ sgn * read (dig1 ++ dig2)
  where digits = some digitChar

data Box = Box Pos Pos deriving (Show)

bbox :: Shape -> Box
bbox (Circle (x,y) r) = Box (x-r,y-r) (x+r,y+r)
bbox (Rectangle (x,y) w h) = Box (x-w/2,y-h/2) (x+w/2,y+h/2)

type Raster = [[Char]]

render :: Box -> (Int, Int) -> Shape -> Raster
render (Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) (cx,cy) s
  = [[ if inShape (x,y) s then 'X' else ' '
     | x <- [x1',x1'+delta..x2']] | y <- [y1',y1'-delta*caspect..y2']]
  where caspect = 2   -- font character aspect ratio
        expand = 1.2  -- expansion of raster beyond bounding box
        delta = max ((x2-x1) / fromIntegral cx) ((y2-y1) / fromIntegral cy / caspect)
        x1' = (x1+x2)/2 - expand*cx' * delta
        x2' = (x1+x2)/2 + expand*cx' * delta
        y1' = (y1+y2)/2 + expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        y2' = (y1+y2)/2 - expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        cx' = fromIntegral cx / 2
        cy' = fromIntegral cy / 2

inShape :: Pos -> Shape -> Bool
inShape (x,y) (Circle (cx,cy) r) = sq (x-cx) + sq (y-cy) <= sq r
  where sq a = a*a
inShape (x,y) (Rectangle (cx,cy) w h)
  =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
    && cy-h/2 <= y && y <= cy+h/2

driver :: String -> IO ()
driver spec = do
  putStrLn "---BEGIN---"
  let res = parse (shape <* eof) "(string)" spec
  case res of
    Left err -> error (errorBundlePretty err)
    Right s -> putStrLn $ unlines $ render (bbox s) (40,20) s
  putStrLn "---END---"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  driver "C(3,8)8"  -- circle radius 8 centered at (3,8)
  driver "R(-1,6)8,3" -- rectangle centered at (-1,6) w/ dim 8 by 3
```

It works fine:

```
λ> main
---BEGIN---



                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                
             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX          
         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX         
       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      
       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX        
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX          
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX            
                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                
                        X                        



---END---
---BEGIN---









     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    










---END---
```

Suppose we want to add a shape, like an `Octagon`.  This requires adding an `Octagon` constructor:

```
data Shape
  = ...
  | Octagon Pos Scalar
  ...
```

Compiler warnings direct us to add the following cases to our functions:

```
bbox (Octagon (x,y) w) = Box (x-w/2,y-w/2) (x+w/2,y+w/2)

inShape (x,y) (Octagon (cx,cy) w)
  =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
    && cy-w/2 <= y && y <= cy+w/2
    && abs (x-cx) + abs (y-cy) <= w / sqrt 2
```

We have to figure out on our own that the parser needs to be modified:

```
shape = ...
    <|> Octagon   <$ char 'O' <*> pos <*> scalar
```

This change requires 7 lines of code added in 4 locations in the source.

Suppose we now want to add an ability to create shapes that consist of unions of other shapes.  This change is similar in scope and requires the addition of 7 lines of code in 4 locations.

Finally, suppose we want to add the ability to "render" to a descriptive text format.  This requires defining a 5-line function in one location:

```
description :: Shape -> String
description (Circle c r) = "a circle centered at " ++ show c ++ " with radius " ++ show r
description (Rectangle c w h) = "a rectangle centered at " ++ show c ++ " with width " ++ show w ++ " and height " ++ show h
description (Octagon c w) = "an octagon centered at " ++ show c ++ " with width " ++ show w
description (Union s t) = "the union of " ++ description s ++ " and " ++ description t
```

The full program follows. It's 94 lines and 3148 characters of source, and it makes no use of advanced Haskell features other than applicative syntax for the parser.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec hiding (Pos)
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

type Pos = (Float, Float)
type Scalar = Float

data Shape
  = Circle Pos Scalar
  | Rectangle Pos Scalar Scalar
  | Octagon Pos Scalar
  | Union Shape Shape
  deriving (Show)

type Parser = Parsec Void String

shape :: Parser Shape
shape = Circle    <$ char 'C' <*> pos <*> scalar
    <|> Rectangle <$ char 'R' <*> pos <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar
    <|> Octagon   <$ char 'O' <*> pos <*> scalar
    <|> Union     <$ char 'U' <*> shape <*> shape

pos :: Parser Pos
pos = (,) <$ char '(' <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar <* char ')'

scalar :: Parser Scalar
scalar = do
  sgn <- option 1 (-1 <$ char '-')
  dig1 <- digits
  dig2 <- option "" ((:) <$> char '.' <*> digits)
  return $ sgn * read (dig1 ++ dig2)
  where digits = some digitChar

data Box = Box Pos Pos deriving (Show)

bbox :: Shape -> Box
bbox (Circle (x,y) r) = Box (x-r,y-r) (x+r,y+r)
bbox (Rectangle (x,y) w h) = Box (x-w/2,y-h/2) (x+w/2,y+h/2)
bbox (Octagon (x,y) w) = Box (x-w/2,y-w/2) (x+w/2,y+w/2)
bbox (Union s t)
  = let Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = bbox s
        Box (x3,y3) (x4,y4) = bbox t
    in  Box (min x1 x3, min y1 y3) (max x2 x4, max y2 y4)

type Raster = [[Char]]

render :: Box -> (Int, Int) -> Shape -> Raster
render (Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) (cx,cy) s
  = [[ if inShape (x,y) s then 'X' else ' '
     | x <- [x1',x1'+delta..x2']] | y <- [y1',y1'-delta*caspect..y2']]
  where caspect = 2   -- font character aspect ratio
        expand = 1.2  -- expansion of raster beyond bounding box
        delta = max ((x2-x1) / fromIntegral cx) ((y2-y1) / fromIntegral cy / caspect)
        x1' = (x1+x2)/2 - expand*cx' * delta
        x2' = (x1+x2)/2 + expand*cx' * delta
        y1' = (y1+y2)/2 + expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        y2' = (y1+y2)/2 - expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        cx' = fromIntegral cx / 2
        cy' = fromIntegral cy / 2

inShape :: Pos -> Shape -> Bool
inShape (x,y) (Circle (cx,cy) r) = sq (x-cx) + sq (y-cy) <= sq r
  where sq a = a*a
inShape (x,y) (Rectangle (cx,cy) w h)
  =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
    && cy-h/2 <= y && y <= cy+h/2
inShape (x,y) (Octagon (cx,cy) w)
  =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
    && cy-w/2 <= y && y <= cy+w/2
    && abs (x-cx) + abs (y-cy) <= w / sqrt 2
inShape p (Union s t) = inShape p s || inShape p t

description :: Shape -> String
description (Circle c r) = "a circle centered at " ++ show c ++ " with radius " ++ show r
description (Rectangle c w h) = "a rectangle centered at " ++ show c ++ " with width " ++ show w ++ " and height " ++ show h
description (Octagon c w) = "an octagon centered at " ++ show c ++ " with width " ++ show w
description (Union s t) = "the union of " ++ description s ++ " and " ++ description t

driver :: String -> IO ()
driver spec = do
  putStrLn "---BEGIN---"
  let res = parse (shape <* eof) "(string)" spec
  case res of
    Left err -> error (errorBundlePretty err)
    Right s -> do
      putStrLn $ unlines $ render (bbox s) (40,20) s
      putStrLn $ description s
  putStrLn "---END---"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  driver "UR(0,0)2,2UC(1,1)0.5C(-1,1)0.5"
```

#### Solution #2

A second method of writing this program is to define a `Shape` class and a collection of instances of this class representing each possible shape.  We might spec out the shapes we want to support as follows, without defining any functionality just yet:

```
class Shape s

data Circle = Circle Pos Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Circle

data Rectangle = Rectangle Pos Scalar Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Rectangle
```

Now, to parse the parse the shape specification, we'll use Megaparsec.  We can't write a `Parser Shape`, because `Shape` is a type class.  We can write a method for parsing the individual shapes however.  This involves adding lines to the class and instances:

```
class Shape s where
  parseShape :: Parser s

instance Shape Circle where
  parseShape = Circle <$ char 'C' <*> pos <*> scalar

instance Shape Rectangle where
  parseShape = Rectangle <$ char 'R' <*> pos <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar
```

We can conveniently parse an arbitrary shape by definining an existential type:

```
data SomeShape = forall s. Shape s => SomeShape s
```

As tempting as it might seem, the following does not work at all:

```
someShape :: Parser SomeShape
someShape = SomeShape <$> parseShape
```

There is, unfortunately, no way to avoid enumerating the individual shapes like so:

```
someShape :: Parser SomeShape
someShape = SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Circle)
        <|> SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Rectangle)
```

Now that we can parse shapes, we'll want to calculate a bounding box.  This involves adding the `Box` type and three lines of the `bbox` definition to the class and two instances:

```
data Box = Box Pos Pos deriving (Show)

class Shape s where
  ...
  bbox :: s -> Box

instance Shape Circle where
  ...
  bbox (Circle (x,y) r) = Box (x-r,y-r) (x+r,y+r)

instance Shape Rectangle where
  ...
  bbox (Rectangle (x,y) w h) = Box (x-w/2,y-h/2) (x+w/2,y+h/2)
```

The rendering function is much the same as before, except for its type signature:

```
render :: (Shape s) => Box -> (Int, Int) -> s -> Raster
```

The `render` function requires an `inShape` method, which involves adding the three lines of the `inShape` definition to the class and two instances.

The driver needs to be modified to handle the existential shape.  In this case, the fix is easy -- just an additional pattern match on `SomeShape`:

```
driver :: String -> IO ()
driver spec = do
  putStrLn "---BEGIN---"
  let res = parse (someShape <* eof) "(string)" spec
  case res of
    Left err -> error (errorBundlePretty err)
    Right (SomeShape s) -> putStrLn $ unlines $ render (bbox s) (40,20) s
  putStrLn "---END---"
```

The full program follows:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec hiding (Pos)
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

data Box = Box Pos Pos deriving (Show)

class Shape s where
  parseShape :: Parser s
  bbox :: s -> Box
  inShape :: Pos -> s -> Bool

type Pos = (Float, Float)
type Scalar = Float

data Circle = Circle Pos Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Circle where
  parseShape = Circle <$ char 'C' <*> pos <*> scalar
  bbox (Circle (x,y) r) = Box (x-r,y-r) (x+r,y+r)
  inShape (x,y) (Circle (cx,cy) r) = sq (x-cx) + sq (y-cy) <= sq r
    where sq a = a*a

data Rectangle = Rectangle Pos Scalar Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Rectangle where
  parseShape = Rectangle <$ char 'R' <*> pos <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar
  bbox (Rectangle (x,y) w h) = Box (x-w/2,y-h/2) (x+w/2,y+h/2)
  inShape (x,y) (Rectangle (cx,cy) w h)
    =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
      && cy-h/2 <= y && y <= cy+h/2

type Parser = Parsec Void String

pos :: Parser Pos
pos = (,) <$ char '(' <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar <* char ')'

scalar :: Parser Scalar
scalar = do
  sgn <- option 1 (-1 <$ char '-')
  dig1 <- digits
  dig2 <- option "" ((:) <$> char '.' <*> digits)
  return $ sgn * read (dig1 ++ dig2)
  where digits = some digitChar

data SomeShape = forall s. Shape s => SomeShape s

someShape :: Parser SomeShape
someShape = SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Circle)
    <|> SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Rectangle)

type Raster = [[Char]]

render :: (Shape s) => Box -> (Int, Int) -> s -> Raster
render (Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) (cx,cy) s
  = [[ if inShape (x,y) s then 'X' else ' '
     | x <- [x1',x1'+delta..x2']] | y <- [y1',y1'-delta*caspect..y2']]
  where caspect = 2   -- font character aspect ratio
        expand = 1.2  -- expansion of raster beyond bounding box
        delta = max ((x2-x1) / fromIntegral cx) ((y2-y1) / fromIntegral cy / caspect)
        x1' = (x1+x2)/2 - expand*cx' * delta
        x2' = (x1+x2)/2 + expand*cx' * delta
        y1' = (y1+y2)/2 + expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        y2' = (y1+y2)/2 - expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        cx' = fromIntegral cx / 2
        cy' = fromIntegral cy / 2

driver :: String -> IO ()
driver spec = do
  putStrLn "---BEGIN---"
  let res = parse (someShape <* eof) "(string)" spec
  case res of
    Left err -> error (errorBundlePretty err)
    Right (SomeShape s) -> putStrLn $ unlines $ render (bbox s) (40,20) s
  putStrLn "---END---"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  driver "C(3,8)8"  -- circle radius 8 centered at (3,8)
  driver "R(-1,6)8,3" -- rectangle centered at (-1,6) w/ dim 8 by 3
```

There's not a tremendous amount of difference between this type class based version and the first ADT version above.  Using a natural, common syntax, it's about 15% longer, as measured by lines or characters, it requires the use of an existential data type, and it includes some complex distractions related to that type.

Now, suppose we want to add an `Octagon`.  The type class implementation should provide much cleaner extensibility for new shapes.  We need to add the type and its instance:

```
data Octagon = Octagon Pos Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Octagon where
  parseShape = Octagon <$ char 'O' <*> pos <*> scalar
  bbox (Octagon (x,y) w) = Box (x-w/2,y-w/2) (x+w/2,y+w/2)
  inShape (x,y) (Octagon (cx,cy) w)
    =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
      && cy-w/2 <= y && y <= cy+w/2
      && abs (x-cx) + abs (y-cy) <= w / sqrt 2
```

Unfortunately, we need to separately add the octagon to the enumeration in the  `shape` parser:

```
someShape :: Parser SomeShape
someShape = SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Circle)
        <|> SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Rectangle)
        <|> SomeShape <$> (parseShape :: Parser Octagon)
```

This seems like defect.  We ought to specify a master list of shapes in one place that can be sequenced at runtime to iterate over all `parseShape` methods (as well as other methods we might later add that require similar enumeration).  A straightforward way of doing this is to define a function that converts a generic `Shape` operation into a sequence of specialized operations across concrete shapes.  That is:

```
overShapes :: (forall s. Shape s => Proxy s -> a) -> [a]
overShapes op =
  [ op (Proxy @Circle)
  , op (Proxy @Rectangle)
  , op (Proxy @Octagon)]
```

Now we can write `shape` succintly as:

```
someShape :: Parser SomeShape
someShape = asum (overShapes op)
  where op :: forall s. (Shape s) => Proxy s -> Parser SomeShape
        op _ = SomeShape <$> parseShape @s
```

This should really pay off now that we're ready to add unions.  We will only need to define a `Union` type and instance containing all the supporting functionality in one place and then remember to add it to `overShapes` for a seamless extension.

Unfortunately, the obvious definition:

```
data Union = Union Shape Shape deriving (Show)
```

doesn't work, since `Shape` is a type class.  We might start with something like:

```
data Union s t = Union s t deriving (Show)
instance (Shape s, Shape t) => Shape (Union s t) where
  parseShape = ...
  bbox (Union s t)
    = let Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = bbox s
          Box (x3,y3) (x4,y4) = bbox t
      in  Box (min x1 x3, min y1 y3) (max x2 x4, max y2 y4)
  inShape p (Union s t) = inShape p s || inShape p t
```

Now, when we try to define `parseShape`, we run into a bit of a problem.  We can certainly define:

```
instance (Shape s, Shape t) => Shape (Union s t) where
  parseShape = Union <$ char 'U' <*> parseShape <*> parseShape
```

but it quickly becomes apparent that we can't make any use of it.  The `parseShape` parser can only parse a known shape, like `Union Circle Rectangle`.  If we want to parse an arbitrary union, we need to parse its components not using `parseShape` but instead by using `someShape` and then constructing an existential `SomeShape` for the `Union`, which can't expose its subshapes in the `Union` type.  So, we'll probably need to write:

```
data Union = Union SomeShape SomeShape
instance Shape Union where
  parseShape = Union <$ char 'U' <*> someShape <*> someShape
  bbox (Union (SomeShape s) (SomeShape t))
    = let Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = bbox s
          Box (x3,y3) (x4,y4) = bbox t
      in  Box (min x1 x3, min y1 y3) (max x2 x4, max y2 y4)
  inShape p (Union (SomeShape s) (SomeShape t)) = inShape p s || inShape p t
```

As mentioned, we'll need to add it to the `overShapes` function:

```
overShapes op =
  [ op (Proxy @Circle)
  , op (Proxy @Rectangle)
  , op (Proxy @Octagon)
  , op (Proxy @Union)]
```

Still, it's nice that we were able to add the support for `Union` in one place plus the `overShapes` enumeration.

Unfortunately, when it comes time to add our `description` method, the extensbility is the wrong way around.  Instead of defining `description` in one place, as we did with the ADT implementation, we need to add a type signature and method calls to all the classes (basically 5 lines in 5 places), just as we did when adding `bbox` and `inShape` during development.

The final program is 113 lines and 3961 characters, about 20-25% longer than the ADT version.  It also contains some real stinkers like:

```
overShapes :: (forall s. Shape s => Proxy s -> a) -> [a]
```

and

```
op :: forall s. (Shape s) => Proxy s -> Parser SomeShape
op _ = SomeShape <$> parseShape @s
```

but at least we can conveniently extend it by adding 7 lines in 2 places instead of 5 lines in 5 places, as long as we're only adding a new shape and not adding functionality that requires a new method -- for that, we need to add 5 lines in 5 places instead of 5 lines in 1 place.

The final program:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Proxy
import Control.Applicative (asum)
import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec hiding (Pos)
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

data Box = Box Pos Pos deriving (Show)

class Shape s where
  parseShape :: Parser s
  bbox :: s -> Box
  inShape :: Pos -> s -> Bool
  description :: s -> String

overShapes :: (forall s. Shape s => Proxy s -> a) -> [a]
overShapes op =
  [ op (Proxy @Circle)
  , op (Proxy @Rectangle)
  , op (Proxy @Octagon)
  , op (Proxy @Union)]

type Pos = (Float, Float)
type Scalar = Float

data Circle = Circle Pos Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Circle where
  parseShape = Circle <$ char 'C' <*> pos <*> scalar
  bbox (Circle (x,y) r) = Box (x-r,y-r) (x+r,y+r)
  inShape (x,y) (Circle (cx,cy) r) = sq (x-cx) + sq (y-cy) <= sq r
    where sq a = a*a
  description (Circle c r) = "a circle centered at " ++ show c ++ " with radius " ++ show r

data Rectangle = Rectangle Pos Scalar Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Rectangle where
  parseShape = Rectangle <$ char 'R' <*> pos <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar
  bbox (Rectangle (x,y) w h) = Box (x-w/2,y-h/2) (x+w/2,y+h/2)
  inShape (x,y) (Rectangle (cx,cy) w h)
    =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
      && cy-h/2 <= y && y <= cy+h/2
  description (Rectangle c w h) = "a rectangle centered at " ++ show c ++ " with width " ++ show w ++ " and height " ++ show h

data Octagon = Octagon Pos Scalar deriving (Show)
instance Shape Octagon where
  parseShape = Octagon <$ char 'O' <*> pos <*> scalar
  bbox (Octagon (x,y) w) = Box (x-w/2,y-w/2) (x+w/2,y+w/2)
  inShape (x,y) (Octagon (cx,cy) w)
    =    cx-w/2 <= x && x <= cx+w/2
      && cy-w/2 <= y && y <= cy+w/2
      && abs (x-cx) + abs (y-cy) <= w / sqrt 2
  description (Octagon c w) = "an octagon centered at " ++ show c ++ " with width " ++ show w

data Union = Union SomeShape SomeShape
instance Shape Union where
  parseShape = Union <$ char 'U' <*> someShape <*> someShape
  bbox (Union (SomeShape s) (SomeShape t))
    = let Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = bbox s
          Box (x3,y3) (x4,y4) = bbox t
      in  Box (min x1 x3, min y1 y3) (max x2 x4, max y2 y4)
  inShape p (Union (SomeShape s) (SomeShape t)) = inShape p s || inShape p t
  description (Union (SomeShape s) (SomeShape t)) = "the union of " ++ description s ++ " and " ++ description t

type Parser = Parsec Void String

pos :: Parser Pos
pos = (,) <$ char '(' <*> scalar <* char ',' <*> scalar <* char ')'

scalar :: Parser Scalar
scalar = do
  sgn <- option 1 (-1 <$ char '-')
  dig1 <- digits
  dig2 <- option "" ((:) <$> char '.' <*> digits)
  return $ sgn * read (dig1 ++ dig2)
  where digits = some digitChar

data SomeShape = forall s. Shape s => SomeShape s

someShape :: Parser SomeShape
someShape = asum (overShapes op)
  where op :: forall s. (Shape s) => Proxy s -> Parser SomeShape
        op _ = SomeShape <$> parseShape @s

type Raster = [[Char]]

render :: (Shape s) => Box -> (Int, Int) -> s -> Raster
render (Box (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) (cx,cy) s
  = [[ if inShape (x,y) s then 'X' else ' '
     | x <- [x1',x1'+delta..x2']] | y <- [y1',y1'-delta*caspect..y2']]
  where caspect = 2   -- font character aspect ratio
        expand = 1.2  -- expansion of raster beyond bounding box
        delta = max ((x2-x1) / fromIntegral cx) ((y2-y1) / fromIntegral cy / caspect)
        x1' = (x1+x2)/2 - expand*cx' * delta
        x2' = (x1+x2)/2 + expand*cx' * delta
        y1' = (y1+y2)/2 + expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        y2' = (y1+y2)/2 - expand*cy' * delta * caspect
        cx' = fromIntegral cx / 2
        cy' = fromIntegral cy / 2

driver :: String -> IO ()
driver spec = do
  putStrLn "---BEGIN---"
  let res = parse (someShape <* eof) "(string)" spec
  case res of
    Left err -> error (errorBundlePretty err)
    Right (SomeShape s) -> do
      putStrLn $ unlines $ render (bbox s) (40,20) s
      putStrLn $ description s
  putStrLn "---END---"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  driver "UR(0,0)2,2UC(1,1)0.5C(-1,1)0.5"
```

#### Conclusions

The bottom line is that the ADT solution is straightforward to develop, understand, and extend.  The type class solution pays a notable price in unnecessary complexity during development, in terms of both unusual type system features *and* the tendency to break the natural flow of development by splitting functions (which are the natural unit of development for functional programs) across separate instances, all for the promise of improved "extensibility" of the final program that is rarely realized in the real world.

I didn't time myself, but I'd estimate that my development time was about the same for each version.  Considering that I wrote the ADT version first and copied and pasted everything I could from that to the type class version, this is quite an indictment of the type class version.  The time I spent thinking through the core logic of the program (the overall design, the technical aspects of rendering the shapes, parsing a scalar in the most awkward way possible, etc.) *plus* the ADT implementation itself took about as much effort as thinking through the stupidities of the `SomeShape` type and fighting the Haskell type system to get the `Union` to work.

My larger experience with Haskell programming is that this is how it usually goes with ADT-based versus type-class-based designs, except it gets worse for bigger programs.